# urllib2.urlopen fails in Django

Tags: django, urllib2

I use `urllib2.urlopen(url)` to get HTML content. The URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/m.html/`.
This method succeeds in getting the HTML content.

But in Django, if I try to get the HTML content, it stops in the function:

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000/m.html/').
```

It just stops. It does not report an error and the server also stops.

I don't know why it works in a single file, but has problems in Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django development server is single-threaded. It can't both serve the view that's requesting the separate page, and the seperate page itself.

However, I've no idea why you would want to do this anyway - if you want some content from within your application, just call the view code itself.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.It help me.I do that because I want to get summary from some page.